# ios - How dispatch_async releases in ARC or Non-ARC mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, automatic-ref-counting, dispatch

I'm testing `dispatch_async`. If I run the following code 100 times, the app makes 100 threads and keeps them. See my code below:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
  [[CustomerDB sharedCustomerDB] updateCustomers:accumulator];
});
```

When are these threads released in ARC? (and non-ARC also).

Thanks both for reading, and for explaining this to me.

Comment: Did you see 100 threads in Xocde's thead list?

Comment: @Amin: I see it in CPU tab at Xcode. It made thread for each dispatch.

Comment: "It made a thread per dispatch"? What I wanted to say: "Why do you care?" You will never break the limits of memory with threads.

Comment: @Amin: Actually, I want to understand how it works, can you please explain more your meaning.

Comment: The main reason for GCD was that you do not have to handle threads. At least you are not able to determine the correct number of threads, because the number of CPU cores and the number of actually running threads is a global resource, the number of threads you start is an app-local resource. So they decided to make threads a global resource, too. The API you get simply lets you enqueue pieces of codes to GDC. On which threads it s delivered and how many threads (sleeping or active) are built, is an implementation detail (thread pool pattern). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern

Comment: Its so helpful. Thanks so much, Amin!